# How to position text on left side of nav bar without effecting buttons on right?

Tags: html, css

I am working on a mobile web application with a **screen size of 360 X 640.**
I want to display text /heading inside the navbar on the left side but I am not able to do it as the buttons on the nav bar have been right aligned by the justify-position end .I tried using float :left also but it does not work.

Please help .
**My frontend**

[image]

**I want to acchieve this(below image)**
I want to move "Talk to Astrologer text in nav bar on the left without affecting position of other buttons. "
[image]

```
//HTML CODE
<div class ="search-bar sticky-top " >

<ul class="navbar navbar-light bg-light   justify-content-end">

    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
      <img src="../assets/search.png" width="30" height="30" alt="">
    </a>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="../assets/filter.png" width="30" height="30" alt="">
      </a>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="../assets/sort.png" width="30" height="30" alt="">
      </a>
</ul>

</div>

<h1 ><b>Talk to an Astrologer</b></h1> //move this inside nav bar on the left
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below code to achieve expected results.

```css
.wrapper{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
  align-items:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<h1 ><b>Talk to an Astrologer</b></h1>
<div class ="search-bar sticky-top " >

<ul class="navbar navbar-light bg-light   justify-content-end">

    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
      <img src="../assets/search.png" width="30" height="30" alt="">
    </a>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="../assets/filter.png" width="30" height="30" alt="">
      </a>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="../assets/sort.png" width="30" height="30" alt="">
      </a>
</ul>

</div>
</div>
```

I have made some change's in your code,

1. I moved your h1 tag to top of all your elements.
2. I have wrapped everything in wrapper div.
3. I apllied display flex property to the wrapper div.

Comment: your welcome but you have approved another answer. @NatashaAnderson Not mine.

Comment: Sorry !!!!! My bad

Answer (score 0):

```
      <div class="search-bar sticky-top ">
        <ul class="navbar navbar-light bg-light   justify-content-between">
          <h1>
            <b>Talk to an Astrologer</b>
          </h1>
          <div>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
              <img src="../assets/search.png" width="30" height="30" alt="" />
            </a>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
              <img src="../assets/filter.png" width="30" height="30" alt="" />
            </a>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
              <img src="../assets/sort.png" width="30" height="30" alt="" />
            </a>
          </div>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

this is how you do it. Wrap all the anchor  tags in one div. put the h1 tag on the same level as it. Then on their parent, call for  `justify-content:"space-between"` which in bootstrap is `justify-content-btween`.